# Conflicting server/client rendering and Webpack’s local css modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, fluxible

I'm using Fluxible to help create an isomorphic app on a new project and it's going swimmingly. I love it so far. I have run into a speed bump, though, and wonder how to get over it.

Here is my Header component thus far:

```
import React from 'react'
import Nav from '../Nav/Nav'

import classNames from 'classnames'
if (process.env.BROWSER) var styles = require('./Header.css')

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {

        // Header classes
        var theClasses = process.env.BROWSER ? classNames({
            [styles.Header]: true
        }) : ''

        return (
            <header className={theClasses}>
                <Nav selected={this.props.selected} links={this.props.links} />
            </header>
        )
    }
}

export default Header
```

You'll see I'm using `process.env.BROWSER` to detect which ENV I'm on. If we're in the client, I require the CSS. If we're on the server, I skip it. That works wonderfully.

The problem comes later in the file, where I build `theClasses` object based on the contents of the `Header.css` file, then use those classes on the Header like so:

```
<header className={theClasses}>
    <Nav selected={this.props.selected} links={this.props.links} />
</header>
```

The problem is because I'm not loading the css on the server, `theClasses` ends up being empty, and the content rendered for the client ends up different than the content on the server. React displays this warning:

> Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the
>   checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server
>   rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the
>   client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which
>   works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering.
>   Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the
>   client or server:
>
> `(client) n28"><header class="Header--Header_ip_OK`
>
> `(server) n28"><header class="" data-reactid=".2ei`

What would you recommend to get this resolved?

---

## UPDATE September 24, 2015

The original issue was that I couldn't get CSS to compile on the server side, so I started checking for the BROWSER like this:

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) var styles = require('./Application.css')
```

If I remove the `if (process.env.BROWSER)` bit I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: src/components/Application/Application.css: Unexpected token (2:0)
  1 |
> 2 | @import 'styles/index.css';
    | ^
  3 |
```

In the following simple CSS file:

```
@import 'styles/index.css';

.Application {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px var(--medium-gray);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    lost-center: 1080px 32px;
}
```

I started this project with the [Fluxible Yo Generator](https://github.com/yahoo/generator-fluxible) which provides two Webpack config files here: https://github.com/yahoo/generator-fluxible/tree/master/app/templates

I updated mine with a few loaders:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './client.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./build/js'),
        publicPath: '/public/js/',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [
                    require.resolve('react-hot-loader'),
                    require.resolve('babel-loader')
                ]
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=25000'
            }, {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: function () {
        return [
            require('lost'),
            require('postcss-import')({
                path: ['./src/'],
                onImport: function (files) {
                    files.forEach(this.addDependency);
                }.bind(this)
            }),
            require('postcss-mixins'),
            require('postcss-custom-properties'),
            require('autoprefixer')({
                browsers: ['last 3 versions']
            })
        ];
    },
    node: {
        setImmediate: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
                BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true)
            }
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'eval'
};
```

So that's where I am… not sure how to get CSS compiled server side. Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should certainly be rendering your server side HTML with the classes otherwise you are missing out on the time to glass perks of an isomorphic application. It means you will still have to wait for the JS to load in order to apply the CSS styles which defeats some of the purpose of building the HTML server side. It also means you can't "[cut the mustard](http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/18948466399/cutting-the-mustard)" and serve old browsers an application with Javascript turned off.

The question is why aren't you rendering the CSS classes on the server? This also confused me for a while but my guess is you don't have two Webpack entry points? One for the client, and one for the server.

If my assumption is correct then take a look at a sandbox repo [here](https://github.com/mderrick/webpack-react-boilerplate/) where I'm doing multiple builds for the [Node server entrypoint](https://github.com/mderrick/webpack-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/server.js) and the [Browser entrypoint](https://github.com/mderrick/webpack-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/client.js) also using Fluxible.

However I would take it all with a pinch of salt for now as it was just a test project for personal use. I have also used this approach with local css where it builds it on both the server and client and it works like a charm.

**EDIT:** I see you are using ES6 so I assume you are indeed building server side? If so what is the reason you don't include the CSS?

Comment: Thanks so much for the great response. This is my first foray into an isomorphic app, so forgive any silly mistakes. I actually started with the Fluxible generator: https://github.com/yahoo/generator-fluxible

It doesn't include CSS, so I added the loaders (`loader: 'style!css?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]!postcss'`) and everything works wonderfully until I try to require CSS on the server. I get this error: `SyntaxError: src/components/Application/Application.css: Unexpected token (2:0) > 2 | @import 'styles/index.css';`

Comment: Whats your CSS file look like? Can you post that in your question? And you are definitely building two Webpack entry points. One for server and one for client?

Comment: Alrighty, updated the original question with more detail.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you want to use `@imports` with local CSS modules. You'd want to require that CSS file in the React component that uses it rather than in a CSS file. Local CSS you should be using `composes` when using classes from another CSS file. This CSS file should only contain classes needed for the component that requires it and not be bootstrapping other CSS files (which I guess it is?).

I cannot explain why you are getting this issue on the server only though (but  `BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true)` is obviously always returning true anyway?).

In other words, I'm not sure.

Comment: It certainly looks like the `css-loader` is being ignored though so `@import` is invalid JS.

Comment: The file I'm importing just contains my base vars. I suppose I could just require that in the main app file…

Comment: How else would you normally import a variables file? Not via `@import`?

Comment: It does seem like this is an issue with my not having separate Webpack configs for server and client. Even when removing the `@import` it hits a snag with the `.` in the first classname. I'm not sure where to get started with learning more about why this doesn't work and how to split the compilation, but I'll take a peek at your repo.

Comment: You use CSS from other files using `composes`. Looking at the Webpack dev server you are using (which I havn't used before) it looks like it takes a config which I imagined was your server build but I might be wrong. In my repo I've built the server entry point manually and serve it with Express instead. The `css-loader` is definitely not being used hence the errors!

Answer (score 4):

You can try [css-modules-require-hook](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-require-hook)

[webpack.config.js](https://github.com/glenjamin/ultimate-hot-reloading-example/blob/9030c76d2942c5b3cbdc37f091b9d361f6ccf627/webpack.config.js#L55)

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
}
```

[server.js](https://github.com/glenjamin/ultimate-hot-reloading-example/blob/9030c76d2942c5b3cbdc37f091b9d361f6ccf627/server.js#L1-L11)

```
require('css-modules-require-hook')({
  // This path should match the localIdentName in your webpack css-loader config.
  generateScopedName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure the server is generating the same markup as the client, which means that you need to use CSS Modules on the server too.

We achieve this in my current project by using Webpack to compile our Node code too. James Long wrote a really good guide on how to set this up, spread across three blog posts:

[Backend Apps with Webpack (Part I)](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I)

[Backend Apps with Webpack (Part II)](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-II)

[Backend Apps with Webpack (Part III)](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-III)

Answer (score 0):

So you have to have two Webpack configs, the first is for compiling browser bundle, the second is for compiling server bundle.

With a standard configuration you have `css-loader?...`:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
}
```

And you get two different bundles.

On a server. All classes are in `css.locals` object:

```
let css = require('styles.scss');
css.locals == { fooClass: 'some_foo_class' }
```

On a browser there is no `.locals`:

```
let css = require('styles.scss');
css == { fooClass: 'some_foo_class' }
```

So you need to get rid of `.locals` in a server version, so that it should be like in a browser.

You can do it using `css-loader/locals?...` in a webpack server config:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/i,
    loader: "css/locals?modules&importLoaders=1&-minimize&localIdentName=[local]_[hash:3]!sass"
}
```

More details here https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/59#issuecomment-109793167